# How to use group by with complex conditions without looping?

Tags: python, group-by, apply

I have the following dataframe:

```
'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00')}, 
'Year': {0: 2021, 1: 2022, 2: 2023, 3: 2024, 4: 2022, 5: 2023, 6: 2024, 7: 2025, 8: 2026},
'Sales_1Q': {0: 5.0, 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: 1.0, 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan')},
'Sales_2Q': {0: float('nan'), 1: 10.0, 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: 10.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0}, 
'Sales_3Q': {0: 5.0, 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: 1.0, 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan')}, 
'Sales_4Q': {0: float('nan'), 1: 10.0, 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: 10.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0},
'Actual_date_1Q': {0: pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: 'NaT', 2: 'NaT', 3: pd.Timestamp('2024-10-12 00:00:00'), 4: 'NaT', 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: 'NaT', 8: 'NaT'},
'Actual_date_2Q': {0: 'NaT', 1: pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00'), 2: 'NaT', 3: 'NaT', 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00'), 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: pd.Timestamp('2025-10-10 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2026-10-10 00:00:00')},
'Actual_date_3Q': {0: pd.Timestamp('2021-01-19 00:00:00'), 1: 'NaT', 2: 'NaT', 3: pd.Timestamp('2025-01-01 00:00:00'), 4: 'NaT', 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: 'NaT', 8: 'NaT'},
'Actual_date_4Q': {0: 'NaT', 1: pd.Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'), 2: 'NaT', 3: 'NaT', 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'), 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: pd.Timestamp('2026-06-22 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2027-06-22 00:00:00')}} )
```

> Task explanation
>
> I want to find the sum of "Sales" columns by year quarters if "Record_date" columns values are in such a period  grouping by the name of the company ("Company" column) and date("Date" column).
>
> For this purpose i wrote the code making a dictionary with year value of the "Year" column as a key and its quarters as items, here it's below.

```
min_year = df.Year[df.Year!=0].min()
max_year = df.Year.max()
intervals = {}

for year in range(min_year, max_year + 1):
    
    q_count = 0
    start_date = pd.to_datetime(f'{year}-01-01')
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(f'{year}-12-31')
    year_interval = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='Q')
    
    list_q_days = {}
    
    for per in range(len(year_interval)):
        q_count += 1 
        if per == 0:
            q_start= year_interval[per] - relativedelta(months =3) + relativedelta(days=1) 
        else:
            q_start= year_interval[per-1] + relativedelta(days=1) 
  
        q_days = pd.date_range(start = q_start, end = year_interval[per], freq = 'd')

        list_q_days[f'{q_count}Q'] = (q_days)
 
    intervals[year] = (list_q_days)

intervals
```

> What I've tried
>
> At this moment I've already fiqured out how to do it using this code:
>
> ```
> %%time
> new_df=pd.DataFrame()
> for group, data in df.groupby(['Company','Date']):  
>     for date in intervals:
>         for q in ['1Q','2Q','3Q', '4Q' ]: #'1Q','2Q','3Q', '4Q' 
>
>             data.loc[(data.Year==date), q] = data.apply(lambda x: x['Sales_1Q'] if x['Actual_date_1Q'] in intervals[date][q] else 0, axis=1).sum() + \
>                         data.apply(lambda x: x['Sales_2Q'] if x['Actual_date_2Q'] in intervals[date][q] else 0, axis=1).sum() + \
>                         data.apply(lambda x: x['Sales_3Q'] if x['Actual_date_3Q'] in intervals[date][q] else 0, axis=1).sum() + \
>                         data.apply(lambda x: x['Sales_4Q'] if x['Actual_date_4Q'] in intervals[date][q] else 0, axis=1).sum()
>             
>     new_df=pd.concat([new_df, data])
> df= new_df.copy()
> df
> ```
>
> But as you can see it's really bad and takes lots of time for processing especially while working with big data. The main problem for me is the first loop `for group, data in df.groupby(['Company','Date'])` as I don't any other ways how can I implement `apply` with `groupby` without catching errors (the most common - `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`).

> What I want to get
>
> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame( {'Company': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'A'}, 
> 'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00')}, 
> 'Year': {0: 2021, 1: 2022, 2: 2023, 3: 2024, 4: 2022, 5: 2023, 6: 2024, 7: 2025, 8: 2026},
> 'Sales_1Q': {0: 5.0, 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: 1.0, 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan')},
> 'Sales_2Q': {0: float('nan'), 1: 10.0, 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: 10.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0}, 
> 'Sales_3Q': {0: 5.0, 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: 1.0, 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan')}, 
> 'Sales_4Q': {0: float('nan'), 1: 10.0, 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: 10.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0},
> 'Actual_date_1Q': {0: pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: 'NaT', 2: 'NaT', 3: pd.Timestamp('2024-10-12 00:00:00'), 4: 'NaT', 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: 'NaT', 8: 'NaT'},
> 'Actual_date_2Q': {0: 'NaT', 1: pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00'), 2: 'NaT', 3: 'NaT', 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00'), 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: pd.Timestamp('2025-10-10 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2026-10-10 00:00:00')},
> 'Actual_date_3Q': {0: pd.Timestamp('2021-01-19 00:00:00'), 1: 'NaT', 2: 'NaT', 3: pd.Timestamp('2025-01-01 00:00:00'), 4: 'NaT', 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: 'NaT', 8: 'NaT'},
> 'Actual_date_4Q': {0: 'NaT', 1: pd.Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'), 2: 'NaT', 3: 'NaT', 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'), 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: pd.Timestamp('2026-06-22 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2027-06-22 00:00:00')},
> '1Q': {0: 10.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 10.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0}, 
> '2Q': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 10.0},
> '3Q': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 10.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0}, 
> '4Q': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0}} )
> ```

Sorry for giving the example of dataframe in code format, as I'm a beginner and this is the first time when I'm trying to ask questions here.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not pretty sure if I 100% understand. But I think you can achieve your desired result more efficiently by using the Pandas library to perform the calculations and transformations.

```
import pandas as pd

# Your original dataframe
data = {'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2022-10-10 00:00:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2023-10-10 00:00:00')}, 
        'Year': {0: 2021, 1: 2022, 2: 2023, 3: 2024, 4: 2022, 5: 2023, 6: 2024, 7: 2025, 8: 2026},
        'Sales_1Q': {0: 5.0, 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: 1.0, 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan')},
        'Sales_2Q': {0: float('nan'), 1: 10.0, 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: 10.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0}, 
        'Sales_3Q': {0: 5.0, 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: 1.0, 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan')}, 
        'Sales_4Q': {0: float('nan'), 1: 10.0, 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: 10.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0},
        'Actual_date_1Q': {0: pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: 'NaT', 2: 'NaT', 3: pd.Timestamp('2024-10-12 00:00:00'), 4: 'NaT', 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: 'NaT', 8: 'NaT'},
        'Actual_date_2Q': {0: 'NaT', 1: pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00'), 2: 'NaT', 3: 'NaT', 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00'), 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: pd.Timestamp('2025-10-10 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2026-10-10 00:00:00')},
        'Actual_date_3Q': {0: pd.Timestamp('2021-01-19 00:00:00'), 1: 'NaT', 2: 'NaT', 3: pd.Timestamp('2025-01-01 00:00:00'), 4: 'NaT', 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: 'NaT', 8: 'NaT'},
        'Actual_date_4Q': {0: 'NaT', 1: pd.Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'), 2: 'NaT', 3: 'NaT', 4: pd.Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'), 5: 'NaT', 6: 'NaT', 7: pd.Timestamp('2026-06-22 00:00:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2027-06-22 00:00:00')}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a function to calculate the Sales for each quarter
def calculate_sales(row, quarter):
    return sum(row[f'Sales_{i}Q'] for i in range(1, 5) if row[f'Actual_date_{i}Q'].quarter == quarter)

# Loop through quarters (1Q, 2Q, 3Q, 4Q) and calculate Sales for each quarter
for quarter in range(1, 5):
    df[f'{quarter}Q'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate_sales(row, quarter), axis=1)

print(df)
```